# 4 Ways to remove an IOS app: is there a preferred method?

Tags: ios

[Per this article,](http://www.macworld.com/article/2364290/four-ways-to-delete-ios-apps.html) there are 4 methods to remove an app:

- tap and wiggle
- from settings
- from iTunes
- when updating

Is there an advantage / preference to use one of these methods over another?

Answer (score 1):

Nope, no advantages between them. In my opinion, just doing a tap-and-wiggle from the home screen is most efficient, but each of the four ways you mention just removes the app. Do whatever's easiest in the moment.